# Почему происходит ошибка "Gosseract fatal error: tesseract/baseapi.h: No such file or directory"?

Tags: windows, golang, visual-studio-code, vcpkg

Пытаюсь использовать библиотеку gosseract. Прописал
`go get github.com/otiai10/gosseract`.

При попытке собрать, получаю следующую ошибку:

```
# github.com/otiai10/gosseract
tessbridge.cpp:5:10: fatal error: tesseract/baseapi.h: No such file or directory
   5 | #include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
     |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Установил `tesseract` через `vcpkg`.

[image: Путь к tesseract]

И указал следующие флаги:

```
go get github.com/otiai10/gosseract -a -ccflags "-I C:\Lib_C\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\tesseract" -ldflags "-L C:\Lib_C\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib"
```

При попытке собрать проект получаю следующее :

```
    PS C:\Users\kiril\source\repos\Go\OCR_Server> go get github.com/otiai10/gosseract -a -ccflags "-I C:\Lib_C\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\tesseract" -ldflags "-L C:\Lib_C\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib"
go: malformed module path "-a": leading dash
go: malformed module path "-ccflags": leading dash
go: malformed module path "-I C:/Lib_C/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/tesseract": leading dash
go: malformed module path "-ldflags": leading dash
go: malformed module path "-L C:/Lib_C/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib": leading dash
PS C:\Users\kiril\source\repos\Go\OCR_Server> go build
# github.com/otiai10/gosseract
tessbridge.cpp:5:10: fatal error: tesseract/baseapi.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Опции должны идти **до** имени пакета. Переставьте github.com/otiai10/gosseract в конец